# JPA Fetch query with 'IS NOT NULL' not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, repository

I need to filter only not null values using `JPA FETCH QUERY` but it's returning all records instead. I have a `Abc` entity mapped with `Xyz` enity. Xyz has one field called `latestId`. So in my requirement, we need to list all `Abc` with `Xyz` where `latestId` should not be null. Please suggest.

```java
public class Abc {
    
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "abc")
    private List<Xyz> xyzList;
}
```

```java
public class Xyz{
    
    private String latestId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "abc_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Abc abc;
    
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface AbcRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Abc, String> {
    @Query("select j from Abc j join fetch j.xyzList s where s.latestId IS NOT NULL")
    List<Abc> findAll(Sort sort);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not place restrictions on a `join fetch`ed collection in the `where` clause, and I'm pretty sure Hibernate should not even have accepted that query. (I will open a bug report.)

Instead you should use a regular `join`.